# Frontend + NGINX can't make a request to backend endpoints (2 different docker containers)

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I am having issues making requests to a backend Django container from a frontend app that is reverse proxied by NGINX.

I have a backend Django server which serves database information, carries out authenticated etc. It is containerised thru a docker container. This is locally served on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`. I then have NGINX `project.conf` as follows:

```
server {

listen 80;
server_name docker_flask_gunicorn_nginx;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

location /static {
    rewrite ^/static(.*) /$1 break;
    root /static;
}}
```

There are a few different endpoints in the backend app, but it fails at the first hurdle which is trying to authenticate at `/api/token/`. When the frontend app makes a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/token/` the following error is returned:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/token/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fc3208f6910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

For completeness the docker-compose for the frontend / NGINX setup is:

```
version: '3'

services:

  my_app:
    container_name: my_app-frontend
    restart: always
    build: ./my_app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    command: gunicorn -w 2 -b :8080 app:server
    env_file:
      - ./my_app/.env


  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - my_app
```

From what I can see on the Django container, the request is never being received by the backend and when I run the frontend app without NGINX it works as expected. As such, I guess that it is an issue with the NGINX setup. I did search through existing questions and some look similar, however I tried the proposed solutions and could not get them to work. For example, I tried changing the API url to point to the docker bridge ip, but that didn't seem to work either. Apologies if this has been answered before, but any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default IP address that gunicorn binds to is 127.0.0.1 which means that it'll only accept connections from inside the container.

Use

```
command: gunicorn -w 2 -b 0.0.0.0:8080 app:server
```

to make it accept connections from outside the container.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however it didn't seem to change the result.